# Move user uploaded video from local to amazon S3 in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a rails app that lets users upload videos. Right now, it works well locally, I want to move it to AWS so that when a user uploads a video, it gets added to my S3 bucket.

Right now, my video uploader.rb looks like this:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

What do I have to change here so it'll be uploaded to S3?

I have also read a little bit about the FOG gem. From what I understand, it helps you upload videos locally and also on the cloud. Will I have to use it here? Sorry if I'm asking this question the wrong way, I'm new here and also to rails.

Thanks a lot and please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the `fog-aws` gem.

In your `Gemfile` add

```
gem 'fog-aws'
```

Create an `initializer` and name it something like `carrierwave.rb`. You will then put your credentials in here:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                          # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',                        # required
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV['aws_access_key_id'],     # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['aws_secret_access_key'], # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['bucket']                    # required
end
```

Use `ENV` variables to hide your AWS information.

You will also want to change `storage :file` to `storage :fog`.

For complete information on file uploads with S3 and Carrierwave check out the [documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#fog).

Due to large video sizes (assuming), I would probably move the upload process into a background job so your web server doesn't time out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! I'll try it out

Comment: How can I make the upload a background job?

Comment: You can use `sidekiq`. In your controller action you can pass the params to the background job.

Comment: Thanks! In video uploader (shown in question), do I leave "store_dir" as it is or do I delete it? And can I test this code locally, or will I have to push all the code to heroku to test?

Comment: You can test locally. As long as you have the correct credentials in, it will be fine. You shouldn't need `store_dir` since that "changes where uploaded files are put", and you are sending the files to S3

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following changes to your Ruby code to upload videos and also allowing streaming of videos.

- Setup AWS CloudFront with [RTMP Distribution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html) for Streaming Videos uploaded to S3.
- Use [Ruby SDK for Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html) to create a Signed URL(Verifying access control) and return the response from a Rails endpoint to the browser, so that using the particular signed URL, the web application running in browser can directly upload the file to S3.

After uploading the file, using AWS CloudFront url, you can stream the video to a video player in browser.

Comment: Hey Ashan, I will look into RTMP and let you know how it goes. It looks like a lot of reading. Also, when you say use AWS CloudFront url to stream, does that mean using that in my video view code or are you talking about something else?

Comment: When you upload files to S3, there should be some intermediary support to play the content of the file while the file is still being downloaded to the browser. There you need CloudFront RTMP distribution. Go through the following doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowStreamingDistributionsWork.html